# Using a service to update the LiveData

Tags: android, service, android-room, lifecycle, android-livedata

I need to know how to update the data of a LiveData object using a Service started from the Main Activity

I'm using [android architecture components](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-and-architecture.html) so I have the object class, the dao interface, the repository the room database and the view model.

Everything is working fine and the data is successfully loaded in the creation of the database in RoomDatabase, however, I need to update the data generated in a service with the problem that it requires the activity context int he next line: 
`LiveData<List<WifiClass>> wifiViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WifiViewModel.class);`

Dao interface:

```
@Dao
public interface WifiDao {

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
  void insert(WifiClass wifiObject);

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
  void insertAll(List<WifiClass> wifiList);

  @Query("DELETE FROM wifi_table")
  void deleteAll();

  @Query("SELECT * from wifi_table ORDER BY SSID ASC")
  LiveData<List<WifiClass>> getAllWifi();

  @Query("SELECT * from wifi_table LIMIT 1")
  WifiClass[] getAnyWifi();

}
```

Repository:

```
public class WifiRepository {

  private WifiDao wifiDao;
  private LiveData<List<WifiClass>> allWifi;

  WifiRepository(Application application) {
    WifiRoomDatabase db = WifiRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    wifiDao = db.wifiDao();
    allWifi = wifiDao.getAllWifi();
  }

  // Get all Wifi objects
  LiveData<List<WifiClass>> getAllWifi() {
    return allWifi;
  }

  //Insert one Wifi object
  public void insert (WifiClass wifiObject){
    new insertAsyncTask(wifiDao).execute(wifiObject);
  }

  private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<WifiClass, Void, Void> {

    private WifiDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertAsyncTask(WifiDao wifiDao) {
      mAsyncTaskDao = wifiDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final WifiClass... params) {
      mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

RoomDatabase:

```
@Database(entities = {WifiClass.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WifiRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase implements Serializable{

  public abstract WifiDao wifiDao();
  private static WifiRoomDatabase INSTANCE;
  public static Context context;

  static List<ScanResult> results;
  private static WifiManager wifiManager;

  public static WifiRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context contextt) {
    context = contextt;
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
      synchronized (WifiRoomDatabase.class) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
          INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), WifiRoomDatabase.class, "wifi_database")
              .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() // Wipes and rebuilds
              .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback) //
              .build();
        }
      }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onOpen (@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db){
      super.onOpen(db);
      new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();

    }
  };


  //Populate the database in the background.
  private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final WifiDao mDao;

    PopulateDbAsync(WifiRoomDatabase db) {
      mDao = db.wifiDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

      if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi disable... Activating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
      }

        results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        wifiManager.startScan();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

      for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
          String ssid = scanResult.SSID;
          if (ssid == null || ssid.isEmpty()){
            ssid = "Hide SSID";
          }
          String bssid = scanResult.BSSID;
          String capabilities = scanResult.capabilities;
          int level = scanResult.level;
          int frequency = scanResult.frequency;
          long timestamp = scanResult.timestamp;

        int passpoint; int channelWidth; int centerFreq0; int centerFreq1; int responder;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
          if (scanResult.isPasspointNetwork() == true) {
            passpoint = 1;
          }else{
            passpoint = 0;
          }
          channelWidth = scanResult.channelWidth;
          centerFreq0 = scanResult.centerFreq0;
          centerFreq1 = scanResult.centerFreq1;
          if (scanResult.is80211mcResponder() == true){
            responder = 1;
          }else{
            responder = 0;
          }
        }else{
          passpoint = 0;
          channelWidth = 0;
          centerFreq0 = 0;
          centerFreq1 = 0;
          responder = 0;

        }

          WifiClass wifiObject = new WifiClass(ssid, bssid, capabilities, level, frequency,
              timestamp, passpoint, channelWidth, centerFreq0, centerFreq1, responder);
          mDao.insert(wifiObject);
        }

      return null;
    }
  }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class WifiViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  private WifiRepository wifiRepository;
  private LiveData<List<WifiClass>> allWifi;

  public WifiViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    wifiRepository = new WifiRepository(application);
    allWifi = wifiRepository.getAllWifi();
  }

  LiveData<List<WifiClass>> getAllWifi() {
    return allWifi;
  }

  public void insert(WifiClass wifiObject) {
    wifiRepository.insert(wifiObject);
  }

}
```

Service:

```
public class Wifi_Service extends IntentService {

  private Handler handler;
  private Runnable runnable;
  private static Context classContext;

  //private static WifiViewModel wifiViewModel;
  static List<ScanResult> results;
  private static WifiManager wifiManager;
  private LiveData<List<WifiClass>> mAllWifi;


  public Wifi_Service(/*WifiRoomDatabase db*/) {
    super("wifi_service");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

  }

  //Populate the database in the background.
  private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final WifiDao mDao;

    PopulateDbAsync(WifiRoomDatabase db) {
      mDao = db.wifiDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      wifiManager = (WifiManager) classContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

      if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        Toast.makeText(classContext, "Wifi disable... Activating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
      }

      results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
      wifiManager.startScan();
      Toast.makeText(classContext, "Scanning...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

      for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
        String ssid = scanResult.SSID;
        if (ssid == null || ssid.isEmpty()){
          ssid = "Hide SSID";
        }
        String bssid = scanResult.BSSID;
        String capabilities = scanResult.capabilities;
        int level = scanResult.level;
        int frequency = scanResult.frequency;
        long timestamp = scanResult.timestamp;

        int passpoint; int channelWidth; int centerFreq0; int centerFreq1; int responder;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
          if (scanResult.isPasspointNetwork() == true) {
            passpoint = 1;
          }else{
            passpoint = 0;
          }
          channelWidth = scanResult.channelWidth;
          centerFreq0 = scanResult.centerFreq0;
          centerFreq1 = scanResult.centerFreq1;
          if (scanResult.is80211mcResponder() == true){
            responder = 1;
          }else{
            responder = 0;
          }
        }else{
          passpoint = 0;
          channelWidth = 0;
          centerFreq0 = 0;
          centerFreq1 = 0;
          responder = 0;

        }

        WifiClass wifiObject = new WifiClass(ssid, bssid, capabilities, level, frequency,
            timestamp, passpoint, channelWidth, centerFreq0, centerFreq1, responder);

      //The problem
        wifiViewModel.insert(wifiObject);
      }

      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
      super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
      Toast.makeText(classContext, "Scanning finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
      Log.d("Service", "null");
    }else {
      Log.d("Service","not null");
      classContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

//The problem
//   wifiViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WifiViewModel.class);
//    mWifiViewModel.getAllWifi().observe(this, new Observer<List<WifiClass>>() {
//      @Override
//      public void onChanged(@Nullable List<WifiClass> wifiClasses) {
//
//      }
//    });


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Destroy scanning service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

I expected that the Service executes, saves and refresh new results in the LiveData List but I can't declare the LiveData List.

Comment: `getAllWifi()` on `WifiDao` should be returning updates to its observers already, based on your inserting of entities into that table. `getAnyWifi()` could do the same, if you had it return a `LiveData`. In general, your service should not be working with Room, but rather with `WifiRepository`, and `WifiRepository` (along with Room) is responsible for reactively delivering updates to interested parties.

Comment: However, if I try to work with the repository from the Service, how can I access to WifiRepository? It is the same case, I would need to pass the activity again, so it is the same problem.

Comment: "It is the same case, I would need to pass the activity again" --`WifiRepository` does not have any reference to an activity, nor should it. It has a reference to an `Application`, and for that, you can call `getApplicationContext()` on your `Service`.

Comment: You should never have a reference to your activity either from your ViewModel or other classes; it simply defeats the purpose of lifecycle aware design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Due to I couldn't call and use the LiveData List because I needed to pass the Application Context and it wasn't acceptable by Android, CommonsWare and The_Martian suggested me to use the repository instead.

Due to my repository calls my room database, I called the database generated in the room class and from there I called the dao interface and the method insert.

The code:

```
WifiRoomDatabase db = WifiRoomDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
db.wifiDao().insert(wifiObject);
```

I'm actually learning about Android Architecture Components so I don't know if this is the best solution but it worked for me.